# How do I invoke a service using Applescript?

Tags: applescript, services

I'm using Circus Ponies NoteBook which doesn't support Applescript methods.  It does support creating services that can clip the current selection into a NoteBook page.  This allows me to select text and use the context menu to paste the text into a NoteBook page.  I'd like to do the exact same thing from an Applescript script.  Is there some way in Applescript to get a handle to an existing service, and send it a message?

Answer (score 3):

Automator services can be run with the `automator` command line utility:

```
do shell script "automator ~/Library/Services/test.workflow -i input -d variable=value"
```

I couldn't get it to work with the service used by Circus Ponies NoteBook though.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the service a keyboard shortcut through
**System Preferences** » **Keyboard** » **Keyboard Shortcuts** » **Services**,

[image: assign a keyboard shortcut]

you can then use the AppleScript **keystroke** command to invoke that shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I made such an Automator action to invoke a Service.

See

https://blog.tempel.org/2015/09/RunServiceForAutomator.html

and

https://github.com/tempelmann/RunServiceActionForAutomator

All that's left is figuring out is how to invoke an Automator workflow from AppleScript. Lri's answer might help with that.